# Hide/Disable mouse cursor in wxWidgets/wxPython on Linux

Tags: wxpython, wxwidgets

I'm using wxWidgets through wxpython.  Under MS Windows (python 2.7, wxwidgets v3.0), the following code hides the mouse cursor (where self is the top-level frame) :

```
cursor = wx.StockCursor(wx.CURSOR_BLANK)
self.SetCursor(cursor)
```

...this works regardless of whether the frame is full screen (ShowFullScreen).

However, on linux (specifically Ubuntu 12.04, python 2.7, wxwidgets v2.8), this does not work -- and it does not seem to throw any error.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Upgrade to wxWidgets 3.0, there is a high probability that this problem is fixed there.

Comment: Perhaps, but I'd like for this app to work with the versions of wxpython and wxwidgets that are available through the repos for Ubuntu 12.04 or 14.04 -- and I don't believe wxWidgets 3.0 is.

Comment: did you ever have any luck with this?